# Library for loading text to textview

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a link and I want to visit it and stores it output in a variable in android studio in kotlin. Please suggest me some way.
Ex -> https://api.github.com/users/myselfdeepdas/followers.
It shows how many followers d0 I have and I want to see who are my followers so I want to visit the link get the name of my followers and display them in a textview just like we do with glide so suggest me some library.

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) to perform API calls and make a model class according to the response of API. After that when you make API call you will get the response, so now you just need to de-serialize / store in variable.

If you are beginner then kindly read about using retrofit and making API calls using it. You will find plethora of resources on YouTube and Google.

[Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gFrXGbQsc8)

**Ask freely, If something is unclear.**